# Create webpack loader to write icon filenames to a single file

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

The `simple-icons` package includes many icons - see https://github.com/simple-icons/simple-icons.

I want to use webpack to generate a list of all icon names in the final bundle, which my app uses to search for icons by name.

I've created the custom webpack loader to incrementally add an icon name to the output json file:

```
// customLoader.js
const fs = require("node:fs")
const { interpolateName } = require("loader-utils")

module.exports = function (content){
  const options = this.getOptions();
  const context = this.rootContext;
  const { filename } = options;
  const name = "[name]";
  const iconName = interpolateName(this, name, {
    context,
    content,
  });

  let iconManifest;

  try {
    iconManifest = fs.readFileSync(filename);
    iconManifest.iconNames.push(iconName)
  } catch (error) {
    // Output file doesn't exist yet so create the icon manifest
    iconManifest = {
      iconNames: [iconName],
    };
  }
  
  this.emitFile(filename, JSON.stringify(iconManifest), null);

  return "";
}
```

And I've added the following rule to my webpack module rule that applies the custom loader to the all simple icon svg files:

```
// webpack.config.js
rules: [
  {
    test: /simple-icons\/.*\.svg$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: path.resolve("webpack-loaders/customLoader.js"),
        options: {
          filename: "user-icons/simple-icons.txt"
        },
      }
    ],
  },
  ...
]
```

Running `npm run build` gives me several errors / problems:

- `fs.readFileSync` always fails and hits the except block
- `emitFile` raises the following error:

> ERROR in Conflict: Multiple assets emit different content to the same filename user-icons/simple-icons.txt

- The `user-icons/simple-icons.txt` file doesn't end up in the final bundle.

Is there anyway to do this or is this webpack loader not possible?

Comment: Seems like a [plugin](https://webpack.js.org/contribute/writing-a-plugin/) might be better suited for your use case. The [example](https://webpack.js.org/contribute/writing-a-plugin/#example) is similiar